# Why I receive sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I faced with error, the sense of witch I can't understand:

I write to models:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))

class UserFile(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_files'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    author = db.relationship(User, foreign_keys=[author_id])
```

I need to do a number of additional steps when I delete a UserFile instance.

When a UserFile instance is deleted directly, I can do whatever I need to do. There is a problem when the User instance is deleted. In this case, I need to remove all UserFile instances associated with the User. But I can't use cascade deletion, because I need to perform additional actions for each UserFile.

I tried using SQLAlchemy 'before_delete' event, but I got an error because it was already running after deletion, although it was called 'before'. I saw this by adding output of the message to the console and not seeing this message in the console until I got the error.

Then I tried using FLASK-sqlalchemy signals. I did:

from flask_sqlalchemy import before_models_committed

```
@before_models_committed.connect_via(app)
def delete_all_user_folders_after_delete(sender, changes):
    for obj, operation in changes:
        if isinstance(obj, User) and operation == 'delete':
            print('files: ', UserFile.query.filter_by(author_id=obj.id, parent_id=None).all())
            for item in UserFile.query.filter_by(author_id=obj.id,
                                                 parent_id=None).all():
                print(item)
                delete_file(item, True)
```

And got error on line:

```
print ('files: ', UserFile.query.filter_by(author_id=obj.id, parent_id=None).all())
```

What is the cause of this error and how do I properly pre-delete all Userfiles before deleting a User?

Error description:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely) (psycopg2.IntegrityError) update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "user_files_author_id_fkey" on table "user_files"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) is still referenced from table "user_files".
```

Comment: what code inside the`delete_file`?

Comment: delete_file recursively deletes all files and their children, and if the file has the is_file=True attribute, it deletes the file in the file system. But the problem is that it does not reach the call of this function. The error happens when I just request a list of user files.

Answer (score 1):

The query performed in `delete_all_user_folders_after_delete()` causes [autoflush](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#flushing), which flushes the deletions prematurely, before your manual cleanup has been done. The default referential action in PostgreSQL is `NO ACTION`, which ["means that if any referencing rows still exist when the constraint is checked, an error is raised"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK). It would seem that you have not deferred the constraint in question, so it is checked immediately.

You could perhaps try the solution proposed in the error message:

```
@before_models_committed.connect_via(app)
def delete_all_user_folders_after_delete(sender, changes):
    for obj, operation in changes:
        if isinstance(obj, User) and operation == 'delete':
            with db.session.no_autoflush:
                fs = UserFile.query.filter_by(author_id=obj.id, parent_id=None).all()
            print('files: ', fs)
            for item in fs:
                print(item)
                # If this queries the DB, remember to disable autoflush again
                delete_file(item, True)
```